# Expect private service method to be called with

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a method that calls a private service which I need to be sure is called with the right params. I'm not sure the best way to do this as I've seen many different things online.

In my test I have the following:

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  const myServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['something']);

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [],
        providers: [
          { provide: MyService, useValue: myServiceSpy },
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should do something', () => {
    component.onBtnClick();
    expect(modalControllerSpy.something).toHaveBeenCalledWith('My arg');
  });
});
```

**Component**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
  ) {}

  onBtnClick(): void {
    this.myService.something('My arg');
  }
}
```

I want to ensure `myService.something` is called with the `'My arg'` argument however the output says: `Error: Expected spy MyService.something to have been called.`

Comment: The code for the test is well written. There are just several ways for you to mock a service and none of those is considered "worst" or "best".

Comment: @ardentia `something` is never called according to the output

Comment: In that case, can you add the error you get when running the test to the question? The way it is right now, it looks like you're just asking for advice on different approaches.

Comment: Okay, so from what I see, your test fails because you are not checking with the actual component instance of `MyService`.  In your `should do something` test you should either inject the `MyService` instance using TestBed and check if its `something` method is called or you should get the instance that is injected into the component itself (`fixture.debugElement.injector.get(MyService)`) and then check if `something` was called.

Answer (score 1):

Did you spy the service function?

```
  it('should do something', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(component['myService'], 'something').and.returnValue();
    component.onBtnClick();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('My arg');
  });
```